# How can I split a string in to multiple words, spaces and tabs in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

For example:

```
String1='Hi what are you doing?'
```

should be split like:

```
List1=['Hi','\s','what','\s','are','\s','you','\s','doing','\s','?']
```

Comment: You should read https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: I think the idea here is that he wants to include all spaces and as well as split words from punctuation.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to split only :

```
String1='Hi what are you doing ?'
print(String1.split())
```

output:

```
['Hi', 'what', 'are', 'you', 'doing', '?']
```

if you want as you shown in the example :

```
print(String1.replace(" "," \s ").split())
```

output:

```
['Hi', '\\s', 'what', '\\s', 'are', '\\s', 'you', '\\s', 'doing', '\\s', '?']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
 s = your string here \nhello" re.split('\s+', s)
```

Another method through re module.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "your string here \nhello \thi"
>>> re.findall(r'\S+', s) ['your', 'string', 'word', 'hello', 'hi']
```

This would match one or more non-space characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
s ='Hi what are you doing?'
import re
re.findall('[a-zA-Z]{1,}|[^a-zA-Z]{1,}', s)
```

output:

```
['Hi', ' ', 'what', ' ', 'are', ' ', 'you', ' ', 'doing', '?']
```